# WPF apply theme to single control

Tags: wpf

I'm using the WPF themes available on http://wpf.codeplex.com but I'd like to apply one of the themes to only a `progressbar` and leave the rest as it is. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is to find out the ProgressBar Style from the Resourcedictionary and paste that on to your Resource. Remember to pull other depending Brushes and Styles which references via StaticResource binding inside the progressbar style somewhere.